Deeplinking with branch.io in an expo-managed app
I'm trying to implement deeplinking using branch in an expo managed app. Have added the config/plugin and unsure how to proceed with implementation especially as I need to generate a dynamic link.
Clear and detailed explanations will be deeply appreciated.
app.config.ts:
export default {
    expo: {
        name: getAppName(),
        slug: 'my_app',
        version: '1.0.0',
        platforms: ['ios', 'android'],
        orientation: 'portrait',
        icon: './assets/images/icon.png',
        scheme: ['myapp'],
        userInterfaceStyle: 'automatic',
        splash: {
            image: './assets/images/splash.png',
            resizeMode: 'cover',
            backgroundColor: '#431F81',
        },
        ios: {
            usesAppleSignIn: true,
            supportsTablet: true,
            bundleIdentifier: getUniqueIdentifier(),
            config: {
                usesNonExemptEncryption: false,
                branch: {
                    apiKey: 'key_live_xxx',
                },
            },
            infoPlist: {
                CFBundleURLTypes: [
                    {
                        CFBundleURLSchemes: [
                            'com.googleusercontent.apps.xxx',
                        ],
                    },
                ],
                UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance: true,
            },
        },
        android: {
            config: {
                branch: {
                    apiKey: 'key_live_xxx',
                },
            },
            adaptiveIcon: {
                foregroundImage: './assets/images/adaptive-icon.png',
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            },
            package: getUniqueIdentifier(),
        },
        androidStatusBar: {
            barStyle: 'light-content',
            backgroundColor: '#431F81',
        },
        androidNavigationBar: {
            barStyle: 'dark-content',
            backgroundColor: '#431F81',
        },
        updates: {
            url: 'https://u.expo.dev/xxx',
        },
        runtimeVersion: {
            policy: 'appVersion',
        },
        plugins: [
            'expo-router',
            'expo-font',
            'expo-secure-store',
            'expo-apple-authentication',
            [
                '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin',
                {
                    iosUrlScheme: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.xxx',
                },
            ],
            ['@config-plugins/react-native-branch'],
        ],
        experiments: {
            typedRoutes: true,
            tsconfigPaths: true,
        },
        extra: {
            router: {
                origin: false,
            },
            eas: {
                projectId: 'xxx',
            },
        },
    },
}

I use the function below to create a buo and generate a link:
type BranchOptions = {
    title: string
    contentDescription: string
}

type LinkProperties = {
    feature?: string
    channel?: string
    campaign?: string
    stage?: string
    tags?: string[]
}

type ControlParams = {
    $fallback_url?: string
    $desktop_url?: string
    $ios_url?: string
    $ipad_url?: string
    $android_url?: string
    $samsung_url?: string
    [key: string]: any
}

export const createJoinLink = async (
    identifier: string,
    options: BranchOptions,
    linkProperties: LinkProperties,
    controlParams: ControlParams,
): Promise<string | null> => {
    try {
        let buo = await branch.createBranchUniversalObject(`${identifier}`, options)

        let { url } = await buo.generateShortUrl(linkProperties, controlParams)

        return url
    } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Unable to create deep link: ' + e.message)
        return null
    }
}

example function call:
const generateDeepLink = (joinId: string) => {
        setLoading(true)

        let options = {
            title: 'Come join in the fun',
            contentDescription: '',
        }
        let linkProperties = {
            feature: 'share',
            channel: 'social',
        }

        let controlParams = {
            $android_url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps',
            $ios_url: 'https://www.apple.com/app-store/',
            $deeplink_path: 'myapp://',
            joinCode: joinId,
            referring_user_id: userId?.toString(),
        }
        createJoinLink(`join-group/${joinId}`, options, linkProperties, controlParams)
            .then((url) => {
                setLink(`${url}?joinId=${joinId}`)
                setLoading(false)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                setError(e.message)
                setLoading(false)
            })
    }

useEffect(() => {
if (joinId) {
generateDeepLink(joinId)
}
}, [joinId])



on Android it crashes and on ios the warning below is logged before crash
ios log
